# how can i read , write and update csv value in python3

Tags: python-3.x

suppose file.csv have only one value (1200) . in a game this is required that value(1200) is changing randamly after getting a new highest score. and return also not working. i'm new in programming so plz check it by heart.

```
def loadScore(self):
    with open('persons.csv', "r") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        return (reader)

def saveScore(self):
    if self.score > self.highScore:
        with open('persons.csv', "w") as csv_file:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
            csvwriter.write(self.score)
            # data.write(str(self.score))
```

Error::
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and '_csv.reader'

Answer (score 0):

in your `loadScore` function you only return a read object, not a value. Changing your function to return the first row only may fix your problem:

```
def loadScore(self):
    with open('persons.csv', "r") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        return next(reader)
```

The `next()` returns the first value in your file here. If you do have multiple values in your file you instead should use:

```
def loadScore(self):
    with open('persons.csv', "r") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            # Do something with each row
            ...
```